# Show $\sum_{j=1}^N{(1-u_j)}\prod_{i=1}^{j-1}{u_i}\leq1$

Tags: inequality, summation

Suppose we have a vector
$\mathbf{u}=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    u_1 & \dots & u_N \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\in [0,1]^N
$
where $u_1 \leq \dots \leq u_N$. I want to show $\sum_{j=1}^N{(1-u_j)}\prod_{i=1}^{j-1}{u_i}\leq1$. Numerical analysis suggests this is true. Do you have any hints how I might approach this? Is it possible to come up with an upper bound lower than $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum simplifies (telescopes) to $1-\prod_{j=1}^{N}{u_j}$, so of course it's at most $1$. One possible upper bound is $1-u_1^N$.